# java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException with java.util.Formatter

Tags: java

I am having a problem with a format specifier. Does that mean the %d I am using?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
   double y, x;

    for (x = 1.0; x <= 7.0; x+=0.1)
    {
        y = x * x - 5 * x + 6;
        System.out.printf("x = "+x+", y = %d", y);
        System.out.printf("\n");
    }

}
```

So that is the code and here is the output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double
x = 1.0, y =    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4045)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2748)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2702)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2488)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
    at wilson_hw03a.java.Wilson_hw03aJava.main(Wilson_hw03aJava.java:15)

Java Result: 1
```

What exactly am I doing wrong? Better yet, what is the error?

Comment: Netbeans has precisely nothing to do with it, and there is indeed an error in your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just noticed another issue. The format specifier for double is `%f` and not `%d`. It could also cause `FormatSpecifier` errors.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double y, x;
    for (x = 1.0; x <= 7.0; x += 0.1) {
        y = x * x - 5 * x + 6;
        System.out.printf("x = %f, y = %f", x, y); // or
        System.out.printf("x = %f, y = %f%n", x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed that right after I tried to run it again. XD But thank you very much!

Comment: Cool then. @NaughtyBear

Comment: @NaughtyBear, maybe you should accept this answer for being more correct. 1+ from me.

Answer (score 6):

There's no "NetBeans" error, there's a Java bug in your program. You've got a format specifier in the wrong section of the printf statement. It needs to be in the String that's part of the first parameter, before the comma that separates method parameters. So not this:

```
System.out.printf("x = "+x+", y = %d", y);
```

but rather this:

```
System.out.printf("x = %d, y = %d", x, y);
```

or if you want a new line:

```
System.out.printf("x = %d, y = %d%n", x, y);
```

Note that in a printf or String.format(...) statement, use `%n` not `\n` for new-lines.

Comment: Thank you. I was unsure what the problem was. +1